# Rebase failed，Cannot merge binary files: monopolee.xlsx

Tags: git

I tried to rebase, to delete a commit_id, and then Auto-merging CONFLICT, `git add` can't help.
there is three homonymic(same-name) CONFLICT files in the stage area, when I "git add ", how can I make sure add the right object？

```
SayHi:monopolee Mylife$ git log --oneline
a7770c0 (HEAD -> reset) 20220325 
d38da28 20220324 
e3767f4 20220323 
ace1b6d 20220322 

SayHi:monopolee Mylife$ git rebase -i e3767f4
drop d38da28 20220324 
pick a7770c0 20220325 

warning: Cannot merge binary files: monopolee.xlsx (HEAD vs. a7770c0 (20220325 ))
Auto-merging monopolee.xlsx
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in monopolee.xlsx
error: could not apply a7770c0... 20220325 
Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
Could not apply a7770c0... 20220325 

SayHi:monopolee Mylife$ git add .
SayHi:monopolee Mylife$ git rebase --continue
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/reset.
SayHi:monopolee Mylife$ git log --oneline
e3767f4 (HEAD -> reset) 20220323 
ace1b6d 20220322 
42b40d2 20220321 
9b4c613 20220320 

SayHi:monopolee Mylife$ git ls-files -s
100644 9693a58c34f039f50e38b097580f77eda2cd9108 0 .gitignore
100644 71e9ad6eaaa3060b57e5d3677c6307f9f5bdc31d 1 monopolee.xlsx
100644 89b6f64ab35a94583e294437a1d82ccc5b35153c 2 monopolee.xlsx
100644 2914685a30cd1ea15836e3d106c44a03ae0408be 3 monopolee.xlsx
```

Comment: This is a bog-standard merge conflict, which you (the programmer) must resolve in the standard ways every Git programmer must understand.

Answer (score 0):

copy stage.theirs to working area, not ours

```
git checkout --theirs monopolee.xlsx
```

git show can also figue out the problems

```
git show 2914685a30cd1ea15836e3d106c44a03ae0408be > monopolee.xlsx
```